# c++ winsock tcp server and client connection with the internet

Tags: c++, tcp, tcpclient, winsock, tcpserver

I have a question and I hope someone can help me.

I have a simple TCP chat programmed with Winsock. Unfortunately, it still works only local at the moment. I would like to have it on the Internet, so I can chat with friends just for fun.

Now I have finally come to the point where I have to unlock ports on my router, and I want to avoid that because then my PC plays the server and as soon as it's off, the chat is offline again. I would run it generally in a virtual server, but I'm not sure how, and where I can get the best server for this.

Do I need a Windows server volume, or are there other cool possibilities?

It would be really nice if someone can give me suggestions on how I can implement this best.

Comment: Obviously, if you intend for your friends to chat while you are offline, you will need to run your server app on a PC that is connected to the Internet 24/7. If you don't want to setup a separate PC for that purpose, then you will have to host another server somewhere else, and likely pay for that privilege. Most common hosting providers will not allow you to run arbitrary binaries on their system unless you pay for a dedicated PC, so you may have to port your server code into a web-based system, like Amazon AWS, etc.

Comment: This is more of an infrastructure/deployment issue than a programming one. There are many hosting options available, but recommendations are off-topic here.